# Runtime Error in Blender: Operator bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide.poll() Expected a view3d Region & Editmesh

Tags: python, scripting, blender

Hello i constantly get the following error message:

```
File "C:\Users\meinuser\OneDrive\Dokumente\wasprivates\Diagramm1.blend\script.py", line 105, in <module>   File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.5\3.5\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 111, in _call_    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), C_dict, kw, C_exec, C_undo)  RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide.poll() expected a view3d region & editmesh
```

Obviously it has something to do with a loopcutslide function so pls help me

The script is here:

[`https://pastebin.com/Fd176j2q`](https://pastebin.com/Fd176j2q)

I tried a lot

nothing worked

i dont know what the problem is

what i am expecting is: that all the mesh parts on the scene are getting loopcutted with 15 cuts to the y axis so the command should be right as i did it manual and copied it from the console so PLS help me

Minimal,Reproducable Example:

```
import bpy
# Select the object by name
obj_name = "Cube"
obj = bpy.data.objects.get(obj_name)
# Switch to Edit Mode
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
# Select all mesh elements
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
# Perform the Loop Cut & Slide operation
bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide(
    MESH_OT_loopcut={
        "number_cuts": 15,
        "smoothness": 0,
        "falloff": 'INVERSE_SQUARE',
        "edge_index": 11,
        "mesh_select_mode_init": (False, False, True)
    }
)
# Switch back to Object Mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and see [ask]

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I added a Minimal,Reproducible Example and changed the Questions